vite + react + typescript => getting an "failed to resolve import prop-types from path-here. Does this file exist error"
some info:

I'm new to typescript/react but I'm familiar with Javascript.

I'm just developing locally for now

I'm using npm run dev to start the local webserver

this is the full error
 [plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "prop-types" from "src/components/MyComponent.tsx". Does the file exist?
 D:/projects/multipath-react-typescript/src/components/MyComponent.tsx:1:34
 15 |    window.$RefreshSig$ = RefreshRuntime.createSignatureFunctionForTransform;
 16 |  }
 17 |  import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    |                         ^
 18 |  export default function MultiPathComponent(props) {
 19 |    return /* @__PURE__ */ jsxDEV(Fragment, { children: /* @__PURE__ */ jsxDEV("h1", { children: [


these are the contents of MyComponent.tsx
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types'    
 interface Props {
     name: string
 }
 export default function MyComponent(props: Props) {
     return (
         <>
             <h1>hello {props.name}</h1>
         </>
     )
 }        
 MyComponent.propTypes = { name: PropTypes.string.isRequired }


the error disappears if I comment out the last line but I believe propTypes and Typescript serve different uses (at least from what I read in another SO discussion)

I have a plain JSX version of the code and I don't encounter any errors there when using "prop-types"

I compared vite.config.js for both TSX and JSX version of the code and they are the same.


